# UI Router resolve not working with component-based states

Tags: angularjs, typescript, dependency-resolver

**Background:**
On an app I am working on, we have a component that is being used in two places.  In one place it's being called from the Material Design `bottomSheet` system.  In another, we are using the component directly via the ui-router state system.

Here's the setup that's causing trouble.  I've already got an `angular.module` statement that has all the proper package dependencies set up - I've been working on this app for months with my team, the problem is specifically the code below, which is what I've just added.

*routes.ts*

```
namespace Main {
    RouteConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];

    function RouteConfig($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('main.myAwesomeFeature', {
                url: '^/myawesomefeature',
                component: 'awesomefeature',
                resolve: {
                    awesomeDefaults: () => new Controllers.AwesomeDefaults(1, 2, 3)
                }
            });

        // Other routing minutiae, unimportant to the question
    }

    angular.module('app').config(RouteConfig)
}
```

*awesomefeature.ts*

```
namespace Controllers {
    export class AwesomeDefaults {
        public constructor(
            number1: number,
            number2: number,
            number3: number
        ) {
        }
    }

    export class AwesomeFeatureCtrl {
        public static $inject: string[] = [
            'awesomeDefaults'
        ];
        public controller(
            public awesomeDefaults: AwesomeDefaults
        ) {               
        }

        // ...Other methods and irrelevant stuff...
    }

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('awesomeFeatureCtrl', AwesomeFeatureCtrl);
}

namespace Components {
    export var awesomeFeatureCmpt: ng.IComponentOptions = {
        bindings: {},
        controller: 'awesomeFeatureCtrl',
        controllerAs: '$ctrl',
        templateUrl: '(Irrelevant, as is the HTML)'
    };

    angular
        .module('app')
        .component('awesomefeature', awesomeFeatureCmpt);
}
```

**Problem:**
Whenever I try to navigate directly to the 'Awesome Feature', not only does my HTML not render, I receive the following console error:

```
angular.js:14525 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: awesomeDefaultsProvider <- awesomeDefaults <- awesomeFeatureCtrl  
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/unpr?p0=awesomeDefaultsProvider%20%3C-%20awesomeDefaults%20%3C-%20awesomeFeatureCtrl  
    at angular.js:66  
    at angular.js:4789  
    at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:4944)  
    at angular.js:4794  
    at getService (angular.js:4944)  
    at injectionArgs (angular.js:4969)  
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4995)  
    at $controllerInit (angular.js:10866)  
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:9746)  
    at angular.js:10154
```

It appears that for whatever reason, `$stateProvider.state({resolve})` isn't properly resolving my `awesomeDefaults` and injecting the value into the `awesomeFeatureCtrl`.

**Question:**
Why isn't `resolve` working as I recall that it should?

To my understanding, the `resolve` object takes each named index on it, runs whatever function is on it, and then resolves it into the controller of the thing in the route, as per the [UI Router Documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki).  It's obvious I'm mis-remembering or mis-understanding something.

Comment: I believe you need to add awesomeDefaults to your component bindings.

Comment: Good suggestion, but it had no effect - this just continues generating the Unknown Provider error.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at your error more closely, I’ve run into this issue before. Try changing this

```
resolve: {
                awesomeDefaults: () => new Controllers.AwesomeDefaults(1, 2, 3)
            }
```

To this

```
resolve: {
                awesomeDefaults: /** ngInject */ () => new Controllers.AwesomeDefaults(1, 2, 3)
            }
```

To properly inject awesomeDefaults.